# MySQL Query Logic by date

Tags: mysql, sql

Restaurants in the area serve various food to customers. As long as customers keep showing up to a restaurant regularly, that restaurant will keep serving the same dish. If no customers visit a restaurant for more than 3 days, then that restaurant will serve a new type of food starting when the next customer visits. Unfortunately, some ingredients were contaminated and caused a few customers to suffer from food poisoning. The restaurants know which food was affected and are now trying to figure out which customers were affected. The restaurants keep their own catalogue of customers, so there is no guarantee that a customer has the same customer ID at each restaurant. All restaurants serve food in the same order. Figure out which customer ate which food.

Sample Data:

Restaurant:

```
restaurant_id   customer_id visit_date
1   1   2020-01-01
2   1   2020-01-01
1   2   2020-01-03
3   1   2020-01-04
2   2   2020-01-14
3   1   2020-01-11
2   3   2020-01-14
```

Food:

```
food_id food_name
1   Spaghetti
2   Chicken and Rice
3   Tacos
```

Desired:

```
Restaurant  Customer    Visit   Food
1   1   2020-01-01  Spaghetti
2   1   2020-01-01  Spaghetti
1   2   2020-01-03  Spaghetti
3   1   2020-01-04  Spaghetti
2   2   2020-01-10  Chicken and Rice
3   1   2020-01-11  Chicken and Rice
2   3   2020-01-14  Tacos
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Did you try creating an intermediate column on restaurant table based on the 3 day logic?

Answer (score 1):

Step1: add a row number to process in the order of date and also add a column food_factor with values as 1 for different food and 0 as same food

step2 : assign 1 for row=1 ( because the first date of customer visit is served with food id=1)

step3: find cumulative sum of id in the order of visit dates per restaurant

step4: Left join with food table on food_id to get foodname

```
SELECT restaurant_id, 
    customer_id, 
    visit_date, 
    f.food_name 
FROM ( 
      SELECT restaurant_id, 
            customer_id, 
            visit_date, 
            Sum(food_factor) OVER (partition BY restaurant_id ORDER BY row) AS foodid
      FROM ( 
             SELECT restaurant_id, 
              customer_id, 
              visit_date, 
              row, 
              CASE 
               WHEN row=1 THEN 1 
               ELSE food_factor 
              END AS food_factor 
             FROM ( 
                   SELECT restaurant_id, 
                    customer_id, 
                    visit_date, 
                    Row_number() OVER( partition BY restaurant_id ORDER BY visit_date) AS row
                    case 
                      WHEN datediff(day,visit_date , lag(visit_date)over(partition by restaurant_id ORDER BY visit_date) >3 THEN 1
                      ELSE 0 
                    END AS food_factor FROM restaurant
                    ) restaurant_food 
                  ) final 
            ) a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN food f 
        ON     a.foodid=f.food_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  restaurant_id,
  customer_id,
  visit_date,
  f.food_name 
FROM
(SELECT 
  restaurant_id,
  customer_id,
  visit_date, 
  sum(food_factor) over (partition by restaurant_id order by row1) as 'foodid' 
FROM
 (SELECT 
  restaurant_id,
  customer_id,
  visit_date,
  row1, 
  case when row1=1 then 1 else food_factor end as food_factor from
(SELECT 
  restaurant_id,
  customer_id,
  visit_date, 
  row_number() 
    over( partition by restaurant_id order by visit_date) as 'row1',
 case 
  when DATEDIFF(visit_date , lag(visit_date)over(partition by restaurant_id order by visit_date)) >3 then 1 else 0 end as food_factor
  FROM 
    restaurant)restaurent_food)final)a 
LEFT JOIN food f on a.foodid=f.food_id;
```